# Calling private method in debug mode inside the class

Tags: python, debugging, pdb

I came across a question about Python debugger when working with pandas inside a class. In short, I could not call the "private method" in the debug console with its original(unmangled) method name.

A sample code would be as follows:

```py
import pandas as pd

class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,1,2,2,3,3],'b':[4,5,6,7,8,9]})
    def __private_method(self,df):
        df['c'] = df['b'] + df['a']
        return df
    def public_method(self):
        new_df = self.df.groupby('a').apply(self.__private_method)
        print(new_df)

foo = Foo()
foo.public_method()
```

The code runs well as a script, either directly running it or with debugger. However, when I add a breakpoint in line 10:`new_df = self.df.groupby('a').apply(self.__private_method)`, start debugging and stop there, and run this line of code in the debug console, I would see the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Foo' object has no attribute '__private_method'
```

However, in the debug console, if I simply put `self.__private_method`, it seems to be able to find the method in the namespace and returns `<bound method Foo.__private_method of <__main__.Foo object at 0x000002011DCA6790>>`.

Lastly, I could run `self.df.groupby('a').apply(self._Foo__private_method)` in the debug console and get no error.

Could anyone help me understand what is going on when I pause in the debug mode and why I could visit `self.__private_method` but unable to call it? Thank you!

Comment: A double-underscored private name doesn't *have* an unmangled name - it's actually stored in the `_Foo__private_method` form.  Any code physically located within the same class would have the same mangling applied, and can therefore use the name; any code located elsewhere doesn't get the mangling.

Comment: @jasonharper Thank you! So, in my case, when a breakpoint (inside the class) is reached and code run in the debug console, is it considered "physically located within the same class" or not? In addition, may I ask for a bit more on why I could find ```self.__private_method``` in the debug console but could not call it? Thanks again